# How many files can be uploaded to a SharePoint Document Library at a time?

Tags: sharepoint, document-library

Using the Upload Multiple Files feature, how many files can be uploaded to a document library at a time? Does it depends on total size of the files?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is only restriction on maximum document size (default is 50MB). You can configure it in Central Administration -> Web Application General Settings page. I don't think there are restrictions on maximum files uploaded at one time.

Comment: So I guess there won't be any limit on number of files until the total size exceeds the set limit??

Comment: I don't think the 'number of files' is related to the individual or total file size. (Unless you run out of space on your DB Server)

Answer (score 0):

It depends which 'uploader' you are using. Microsoft has changed this at some stage with a service pack.

The 'drag and drop' uploader maxes out at 100 files (without giving a decent message). The 'Treeview' based uploader does not have a limit I believe, but has other annoying limitations.

([Copy from my answer on the same question on SharePoint Overflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9288/how-many-files-can-be-uploaded-to-a-document-library-at-a-time/9289#9289))